# What is BrowserRouter and do I need it to setup a react server that works online?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages

I have just finished creating the beginnings of a website. This website works very well on my localhost. I pushed this website to my GitHub account, and I am trying to run this website with GitHub Pages.

I finished all of the steps except for the last step on this guide: https://itnext.io/so-you-want-to-host-your-single-age-react-app-on-github-pages-a826ab01e48

On another guide I was looking at, this step wasn't included, so I thought I might be able to host a website without it. In this step, the writer explains how they needed to add a basename to their BrowserRouter Component.

My issue is that I don't have a BrowserRouter Component and Router Components, nor do I need them to run my website locally. Are these components required for running a website on a GitHub Pages website?

All of my code is on my GitHub branch: https://github.com/NumaKarolinski/PersonalWebsite

P.S. When I go to the URL of my website there is a 404 Error. On Chrome the console says that I have an issue with favicon.ico, but I don't think that this is an issue because when I open the website on Microsoft Edge I do not get this favicon.ico issue, but I do get the 404 Error.

Answer (score 0):

Why would a router be needed ? If you need client-side routing for the specifics needs of your SPA, go for it. Otherwise, don't, it is not by any means "needed".
Also, there is no such thing as a "react server" (but there are server-side rendered and/or statically generated react apps).

That being said, don't reinvent the wheel by trying to deploy a React app on GH Pages/Netlify or similar yourself.

Go the Gatsby route, or similar. It's been made for this purpose ! :)